# How to set docker memory and cpus from command line?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, memory, command-line

I have installed docker both on a computer running Ubuntu and on a Mac. I can easily set the total memory (and cpus) allowed for docker from the mac app, but I can't find a way to do the same from command line on Ubuntu. 
Note: I want them to be applied for all containers and not a per container configuration. That means that if I run `docker info` it should output the new values set.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: have a look here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: On native Linux, Docker can use all available system memory, unless you limit it per-container.  On MacOS there's a hidden Linux VM and the Docker Desktop control affect that VM's memory allocation.